# What does ありゃあねぇ stand for?

Tags: slang, sentence, writing-identification

[image]

ありゃあねぇ= あればいい? From context is seems that but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. ありゃあね here would uncontract to あればね. Just as we can say 'If only they had taste as good as yours' without strictly finishing the thought, simple ば or たら can be used to imply a wish in Japanese